# How do I find hardware information about the fan in my laptop?

Tags: hardware, fan

Can you help me with finding all the hardware information (parameters) and configuration files about the fan in my laptop?

I'm interested in commands that will find that information and configuration files.

Answer (score 3):

Try [system profiler and benchmark](http://hardinfo.berlios.de/Downloads) also called hardinfo .
Or you can install it by typing in a terminal `sudo apt-get install hardinfo`

They have all the info you need about your computer, good luck.

Comment: FYI, hardinfo is in the package repositories.

Comment: Forgot about that, it's fixed now

Comment: Hardinfo application freezes on my laptop when I click on Sensors. I'm looking rather for command line tools and configuration files with settins for my fan.